# How to verify Aadhar number in iOS application?

Tags: ios, sdk, frameworks, aadhaar

I want to create application in which user will enter his Aadhar number.if Aadhar number is valid then user get OTP on his/her registered mobile number

I learned about AadharAPI but there is no information about iOS SDK integration

Comment: I think you'd want to explain to people what Aadhar is first. :'D

Comment: ohh yes :D but i can't get any information for how to integrate in iOS there is SDK available for Android and Web only @RakeshaShastri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a web view to achieve that. Follow below steps.
1. Create a web page that will take Aadhar Number and do authentication. Create call back request for sending Success and Failure response back to iOS
2. Call that web page in iOS view controller using web view
3. For success and failure responses implement call back request in web view and fetch the details.